# How can i add an image into a image using UWP XAML C#?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I use a button and its background is an image.I want to put an logo into it but i don't know how to put an image into image. Help me please thanks

Comment: Could you please post your xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Grid layout and place your images into it:

```
 <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Assets/LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
```